# Azure CSP customer subscription creation partner center powershell script fails when using Access Tokens

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am running the below script to create an Azure CSP Customer subscription. This works when i use DeviceAuthentication. However, it fails when i use the Access token. (It is not able to retrieve billingaccount). It also doesn't throw any error message.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $custID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $subscriptionName
)

If (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PartnerCenter) {
    Write-Host "Module exists"
} 
else {
    Install-Module -Name PartnerCenter -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Force
}
$access_token = "<AccessToken>"
try {
    #Connect-PartnerCenter -UseDeviceAuthentication
    Connect-PartnerCenter -AccessToken $access_token -TenantID "<TenantID>"
    $BillingAccount = Get-PartnerAzureBillingAccount | Where-Object {$_.AgreementType -eq 'MicrosoftCustomerAgreement'}
    Get-PartnerCustomer -CustomerId $CustID
    $BillingAccount
    $Subscription = New-PartnerAzureSubscription -BillingAccountName $BillingAccount.Name -CustomerId $custID -DisplayName $subscriptionName
    "New Subscription created sucessfully. Details below."
    $Subscription
}
catch {
    "Error creating New Subscription"
}
```

I cannot use the GUI based authentication as i am running Azure Automation runbook and it does not allow login popups. I need to make this work with Access Tokens

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the access token has required permissions to generate it and the generated access token might expire every time. In that case, refresh the token or use below code inside the loop to generate a token every time to avoid this kind of issues.

```
$client_id = "applicationID"
$tenant_id = "tenantID"
$credential = Get-Credential
New-PartnerAccessToken -ApplicationId $client_id -Scopes 'https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com' -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant $tenant_id -UseAuthorizationCode
```

Refer [article](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/how-to-connect-to-delegated-office-365-tenants-using-the-secure-app-model/#:%7E:text=Connect%20to%20delegated%20Office%20365%20tenants%20via%20PowerShell,access%20tokens%20to%20connect%20to%20tenants%20via%20PowerShell) by @Elliot Munro for more relevant information about `connect-partnercenter`.

*I tried it in my environment and was successfully connected.*

[image]